# Pattern extraction in R language

Tags: r

i am a new programmer in R..my data is given below, i want to extract two or more words from this corpus.my example code also given below

MY CORPUS OR document

---

> apple tops in online shopping us retail sales on apple aapl mobile
>   devices were  times higher than sales on google goog androidpowered
>   smartphones and tablets accounting for  of all online sales activity
>   according a report from ibm smarter commerce owners of apple ios
>   devices spent an average of  per    pm et apple facing margin pressure
>   wells fargo securities downgraded apple aapl stock to market perform
>   from outperform saying the companys gross profit margin will come
>   under pressure with release of its next smartphone which is likely to
>   be called iphone  as wireless service providers pull back on
>   subsidizing the retail stock goes down and sometime move up   pm et
>   synaptics follows apple into fingerprint id market synaptics syna a
>   leading maker of touch interfaces for computers and mobile devices is
>   expanding into the growing market for fingerprint identification the
>   san jose califbased company touted its november acquisition of
>   fingerprint id company validity sensors as an integral part of its 
>   pm et apple ios beats google android in mobile shopping us retail
>   sales on apple aapl mobile devices were five times higher than sales
>   recorded on google goog androidpowered smartphones and tablets
>   according to a report released thursday by ibm smarter commerce a unit
>   of ibm ibm but ibm which tracks more than  us retail websites found
>
> ultra hd curvedscreen tvs wearables big at ces sale down  ultra
>   highdefinition tvs wearable computers and sensors and consumer d
>   printers are among the products expected to make waves next week at
>   the consumer electronics show in las vegas officially known as the
>   international ces it is expected to attract  attendees more than  
>   pm et four major products apple might unveil in buy up apple aapl ceo
>   tim cook has talked about  being an exciting year for new apple
>   products including new categories but hes been intentionally vague
>   industry analysts have weighed in with their best guesses on what new
>   products we can expect from apple in the year ahead

---

I have declared manually a dictionary for keyword extracting but the problem is that, i am not able to extract two or more keywords occurrences or frequency from this corpus.
any suggestion

My Code example

this my corpus code

```
corpus<-Corpus(DirSource("corpus"),readerControl=list(readPlain,language="en"))
```

this is my dictionary

```
which_words<-Dictionary(c("move up","sale","stock goes up"))
```

this is my matching code

```
total<-(DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,list(dictionary = which_words)))
```

this is my result

```
inspect(total)
       Terms
Docs   move up sale stock goes up
1.txt     0      1     0
```

Comment: I am not sure that `move up` or `stock goes up` are a "single" word.

Comment: Dear Sir, move up is two word, stock goes up three words ,and sale is one word . i put it in a single string like "move up","sale","stock goes up".

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can concatenate words in a single word:

```
txt <- gsub("move up","moveup",txt)
txt <- gsub("goes up","goesup",txt)
txt <- gsub("goes down","goesdown",txt)

library(tm)

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
which_words <- c("moveup","sale","goesup","goesdown")
total <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,list(dictionary = which_words))
inspect(total)
Docs goesdown goesup moveup sale
   1        1      0      1    1
```

But , it is better to see some sentiment analysis package to do this.